# RHEL6 autofs maps with subdirectories and LDAP

Tags: redhat, rhel6, automount, autofs

All the documentation I see shows, even for file based, mounts that will show up on the client computer like
/test/mymount
and you can have as many
/test/mymount2
/test/mymountN
as you want.

What I can't find documentation on is
/test/mymount/subdir
or
/test/mymount/subdir/mysubdirN
...
Attempting to set via LDAP such as
entry attribute being
mymount/subdir
but autofs says that's an invalid path or mount name.

What's weird is this works using NIS...

Is there any docs that point how to specify this in LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can do this in an ugly way by making a new mount map entry like auto.folder2 and specifying the nisObject entry cn in auto.master like /test/mymount and then any nisObjects inside the nisMap auto.folder2 will end up at /test/mymount/subdir...